# How to find repeat values between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large data set in an excel spreadsheet. I imported the data to SQL Server with a date between 01/01/2016 and 12/31/2017. I want to fetch data that repeats both 2016 and 2017 years. My data table looks like:

```
   Date       Type         Customer 
 01/01/2016 Invoice 1036     Name1  
 01/01/2016 Invoice 1036     Name4  
 01/01/2016 Invoice 1036     Name5  
 01/09/2017 Invoice 1036     Name3  
 01/20/2017 Invoice 1036     Name6  
 01/12/2017 Invoice 1036     Name1  
 01/11/2017 Invoice 1036     Name7
```

I want which customers repeat after comparing their dates. I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sub-query and join

```
with t1 as
(  select * from t where year(date)='2016'
), t2 as
(
  select * from t where year(date)='2017'
) select t1.* from t1 join t2
on t1.Customer=t2.Customer and t1.type=t2.type
```

Comment: thanks but i getting error like  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-01-2016' to data type int.

Comment: @Thennarasu its normal and expected if you going to convert this type data to int

Comment: yes actually i have   imported data from Excel i have one column date  that columns i am trying to compare when i was enter original  date i getting this error

Comment: in case of data import process  data cleaning is much important